# Ansible - SNMP Service on Windows 10 is not appearing

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible, windows-10

I am installing SNMP service on Windows 10 through ansible. As per ansible output, it is getting installed but not appearing in the services.msc.

Playbook task

```
tasks:
   - name: Install Service
     ansible.windows.win_powershell:
        script: add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name "SNMP.Client----0.0.1.0"
```

output

```
changed: [10.65.150.240] => {
"changed": true,
"debug": [],
"error": [],
"host_err": "",
"host_out": "",
"information": [],
"invocation": {
    "module_args": {
        "arguments": null,
        "chdir": null,
        "creates": null,
        "depth": 2,
        "error_action": "continue",
        "executable": null,
        "parameters": null,
        "removes": null,
        "script": "add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name \"SNMP.Client----0.0.1.0\""
    }
},
"output": [
    {
        "LogLevel": {
            "String": "WarningsInfo",
            "Type": "Microsoft.Dism.Commands.LogLevel",
            "Value": 2
        },
        "LogPath": "C:\\windows\\Logs\\DISM\\dism.log",
        "Online": true,
        "Path": null,
        "RestartNeeded": false,
        "ScratchDirectory": null,
        "SysDrivePath": null,
        "WinPath": null
    }
],
"result": {},
"verbose": [],
"warning": []
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The name of the feature is actually a little different. It should contain the `~` character instead of `-`.

Change the install command to this:

```
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name "SNMP.Client~~~~0.0.1.0"
```

Unfortunately, the output from the install seems to be the same whether or not the correct name was used. If you need to confirm it was installed, I suggest checking the state afterward to verify it's "Installed."

```
PS C:\> Get-WindowsCapability -Online -Name "SNMP.Client~~~~0.0.1.0" | Select State

    State
    -----
Installed
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But we are getting permission denied error when we used the ~ instead of -.
                "message": "Access is denied.\r\n",
                "source": "System.Management.Automation",
                "type": "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException"
            },
            "fully_qualified_error_id": "Microsoft.Dism.Commands.AddWindowsCapabilityCommand",
            "output": "add-WindowsCapability : Access is denied.\r\n\r\nAt line:1 char:1\r\n+ add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name \"SNMP.Client~~~~0.0.1.0\"\r\n+

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with Ansible, but have you verified it has administrator permissions? That was required for the install of the feature when I added it here.